# Run PHP cronjob on hosting system

Tags: php, linux

I wish to run a lengthy PHP script on a hosted Linux system (for example Godaddy or OVH). The script is supposed to be able to run for 1 or 2 hours. I suppose that would be a cronjob.

I have tried to make a Linux command call my PHP with following:

```
print `echo /usr/local/bin/php -q myScript.php | at now`;
```

But this does not return any feedback, and the script is not processed.
Using 'which PHP' I could check that the path to PHP is correct.
Also, other simple commands like `ls -l` give me proper output.

I am not sure how to further troubleshoot this, or if it is even possible.

How would you recommend to proceed to run my PHP script?

---

Update:

I have tried putting the whole path to the script and it made no difference.

Since I do not know how to edit cron on the hosting account, I am calling my PHP script by calling another PHP file. I have:

triggerScript.php:

```
<?php
print `/usr/local/bin/php /path/to/myScript.php`;
?>
```

and myScript.php:

```
<?php
print `ls -l`;
?>
```

Now I run triggerScript.php on my browser, and the page seem to load for a while but I get a browser error "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".

Comment: Have you tried supplying the proper path to the script ?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not just editing your `crontab(5)` file with `crontab -e`?

Comment: @tuscon expanding on @sarnold just add it to your crontab. Any output the script generates can be mailed to you by adding MAILTO on top. Or you can have the script itself mail you

Comment: Does the command "/usr/local/bin/php -q myScript.php" run the script? Does it still work if you're in a different directory?

Comment: you don't need a cron job to run a script in the background, you can just call it with exec()

Comment: @Khez Thanks for the idea. Yes, I just tried that but it made no difference.

Comment: @sarnold I do not know how to edit the crontab on this hosted account. I run my Linux shell commands by calling a PHP script which prints the Linux shell commands.

Comment: Have you tried just asking your host? If they so "No" then don't try to hack around that, because they will probably find out at some point and kick you off. If they won't let you, you need a new host. simple as that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you say GoDaddy?
Check this out:

http://help.godaddy.com/topic/67/article/3547?locale=en

All the linux shared hosting I use/used has option to setup cron from control panel. You do not have to setup by running a command from php...
Godaddy supports cron, even with the lowest priced account. I use this features on some of my sites hosted on Godaddy.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was actually using OVH and they had a similar menu item to schedule tasks and call PHP scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have shell access and cannot get real cron jobs.
Use one of the free or commercial "web cron" providers that regularly call one of your web php scripts. Combine that with a `set_time_limit` call in your php script so it does not get killed for runnning too long.

Comment: Thanks. I suspect I do not have the rights to run cron jobs, but I can actually run commands like 'ls -l' inside a PHP.